# AutoCompleteTextView without dictionary hints

Tags: android, android-widget, autocompletetextview

I have an Autocompletetextview field. The problem is that in portrait view, in addition to the suggestions from my array that show up top, a bar pops up below with suggestions from a dictionary. I can't seem to figure out how to disable those.

Comment: Can you show how you are defining your AutoCompleteTextView. My problem is exactly the opposite. I want to show dictionary suggestions along with the popup but I don't see any dictionary suggestions.

Comment: I wish I could help.  My problem was a year ago and I no longer have that code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your XML try, `inputType="textNoSuggestions"`.

From the [Developer doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType):

> textNoSuggestions - Can be combined
>   with text and its variations to
>   indicate that the IME should not show
>   any dictionary-based word suggestions.
>   Corresponds to
>   TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS.